# How do you create a new Javascript object from GWT JSNI?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

How do you create a new Javascript object from GWT using JSNI? It's not listed in the documentation. It works when I move all the JS to .html files (but causes another unrelated problem).

Java Code:

```
private static native void createPicker() /*-{
    var picker = new $wnd.google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
        ....
```

Error:

> com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (ReferenceError) @com.onix.sdm.client.SDM_Mailer::createPicker()([]): google is not defined

From browser console:

```
> google
  >Object {picker: Object}
```

Reference:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadPicker() {
      gapi.load('picker');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=loadPicker"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There were many, many variables prefixed with a package name. It wasn't just the new object that had to be prefixed, but all of the variables as well, like

> var view = new $wnd.google.picker.DocsView($wnd.google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS);
>
> .enableFeature($wnd.google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)

Overall a big pain, no line #s, etc, but that's what they pay me the money for.